# error-safe templating with brew / whisker

Tags: r, templates

An external program needs an input file with some control parameters, and I wish to generate those automatically using R. Usually, I simply use `paste("parameter1: ", param1, ...)` to create the long string of text, and output to a file, but the script rapidly becomes unreadable. This problem is probably well suited to whisker,

```
library(whisker)

template= 'Hello {{name}}
You have just won ${{value}}!
'

data <- list( name = "Chris", value= 124)

whisker.render(template, data)
```

My issue here, is that there's no safe-checking that `data` contains all the required variables, e.g.

```
whisker.render(template, data[-1])
```

will silently ignore the fact that I forgot to specify a name. My end-program will crash, however, if I fail to produce a complete config file.

Another templating system is provided by `brew`; it has the advantage of actually evaluating things, and potentially this can also help detect missing variables,

```
library(brew)

template2 = 'Hello <%= name %>
You have just won $<%= value %>!
'

data <- list( name = "Chris", value= 124)

own_brew <- function(template, values){
  attach(values, pos=2)
  out = capture.output(brew(text = template)) 
  detach(values, pos=2)
  cat(out, sep='\n')
  invisible(out)
}

own_brew(template2, data)
own_brew(template2, data[-1]) # error
```

However, I am stuck with two issues:

- `attach() ... detach()` is not ideal, (gives warnings every now and then), or at least I don't know how to use it properly. I tried to define an environment for `brew()`, but it was too restrictive and didn't know about `base` functions anymore...
- even though an error occurs, a string is still returned by the function. I tried to wrap the call in `try()` but I have no experience in error handling. How do I tell it to quit the function producing no output?

**Edit:** I have updated the `brew` solution to use a new environment instead of `attach()`, and stop execution in case of an error. (`?capture.output` suggests that it was not the right function to use here, since "An attempt is made to write output as far as possible to file if there is an error in evaluating the expressions"...)

```
own_brew <- function(template, values, file=""){
  env <- as.environment(values)
  parent.env(env) <- .GlobalEnv 
  a  <-  textConnection("cout", "w")
  out <- try(brew(text = template, envir=env, output=a))

  if(inherits(out, "try-error")){
    close(a)
    stop()
  }
  cat(cout, file=file, sep="\n")
  close(a) 
  invisible(cout)
}
```

There must be an easier way with `tryCatch`, but I can't understand a single thing in its help page.

I welcome other suggestions on the more general problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using regular expressions to retrieve the variable names from the template, you could validate before rendering, e.g.,

```
render <- function(template, data) {
    vars <- unlist(regmatches(template, gregexpr('(?<=\\{\\{)[[:alnum:]_.]+(?=\\}\\})', template, perl=TRUE)))
    stopifnot(all(vars %in% names(data)))
    whisker.render(template, data) 
}

render(template, data)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's one option. I do like the fact that brew has the ability to evaluate code.

Comment: I used whisker in my example, but of course this could be easily altered to work with brew templates instead.

Comment: easily ... if one knows regular expressions :)

Comment: Note that this solution will not work if there are lists in the data, e.g. this kind of syntax {{#repo}}<b>{{name}}</b>{{/repo}} from http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html

Answer (score 4):

The new [`glue` package](https://github.com/tidyverse/glue) provides another alternative,

```
library(glue)
template <- 'Hello {name} You have just won ${value}!'
data <- list( name = "Chris", value= 124)

glue_data(template, .x=data)
# Hello Chris You have just won $124!

glue_data(template, .x=data[-1])
# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'name' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Since version 1.1.0 (on CRAN 19 Aug, 2016), the [`stringr` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=stringr) includes the `str_interp()` function (unfortunately not mentioned in the NEWS file of the release).

```
template <- "Hello ${name} You have just won $${value}!"
data <- list( name = "Chris", value= 124)

stringr::str_interp(template, data)
```

> ```
> [1] "Hello Chris You have just won $124!"
> ```

```
stringr::str_interp(template, data[-1L])
```

> ```
> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'name' not found
> ```

Answer (score 1):

While preparing the [`stringr` answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46110386/3817004) I noticed that OP's questions concerning the usage of `brew()` hasn't been addressed so far. In particular, the OP was asking how to provide his `data` to the environment and how to prevent a character string being returned in case of an error.

The OP has created a function `own_brew()` which wraps the call to `brew()`. Although, there are alternative package available now, I feel the original question deserves an answer.

This is my attempt to improve [baptiste's version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16595621/3817004):

```
own_brew <- function(template, values, file=""){
  a  <-  textConnection("cout", "w")
  out <- brew::brew(text = template, envir=list2env(values), output=a)
  close(a)
  if (inherits(out, "try-error")) stop()
  cat(cout, file=file, sep="\n")
  invisible(cout)
}
```

The main differences are that `list2env()` is used  to pass the list of `values` to `brew()` and that the call to `try()` is avoided by testing the return value `out` for an error.

```
template <- "Hello <%= name %> You have just won $<%= value %>!"
data <- list( name = "Chris", value= 124)

own_brew(template, data)
```

> ```
> Hello Chris You have just won $124!
> ```

```
own_brew(template, data[-1L])
```

> ```
> Error in cat(name) : object 'name' not found
> Error in own_brew(template, data[-1L]) :
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The new [jinjar](https://davidchall.github.io/jinjar/) package will raise an error if a data variable is missing. It also provides the ability to explicitly handle missing values in your template.

```r
library(jinjar)

# if name missing, raise error
template <- 'Hello {{ name }}
You have just won ${{ value }}!'

render(template, value = 124)
#> Error: [inja.exception.render_error] (at 1:10) variable 'name' not found


# if name missing, use default
template <- 'Hello {{ default(name, "world") }}
You have just won ${{ value }}!'

render(template, value = 124)
#> [1] "Hello world\nYou have just won $124!"


# if name missing, skip section
template <- '{% if exists("name") %}Hello {{ name }}{% endif -%}
You have just won ${{ value }}!'

render(template, value = 124)
#> [1] "You have just won $124!"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>