# sprintf format strings: reference by name?

Tags: r

In Python, you can specify string formats by name (this is of course a silly example):

```
parameters = {'label':'months', 'april':4,'may':5,'june':6}
formatstring = '%(label)s: %(april)d %(may)d %(june)d'
outputstring = formatstring % parameters
```

(The `formatstring % parameters` notation is the Python equivalent to `do.call(sprintf,c(formatstring,as.list(parameters)))` in R.)

The output string would be "`months: 4, 5, 6`". parameters is stored as a key-value pair (which might be called a dictionary, hashtable, or named list in various languages). The string format `%(text)s` allows you to reference which dictionary item (`text`) should be formatted in that slot.

Is there anything equivalent in R, or you have you found a good workaround?

Comment: In your own interest you shouldn't assume that everyone able to help you with R understands Python. Explain what the Python code does.

Comment: this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023274/how-to-do-printf-in-r) provides some useful background on "printf" in R.

Comment: Thanks @Roland, I have added explanation.

Comment: I would use the `brew` or `whisker` package for this; they're powerful templating tools. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595621/error-safe-templating-with-brew-whisker) for an example.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/46085274/149988

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**1.** Try `gsubfn` in the [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com):

```
library(gsubfn)
parameters <- list(label = "months", april = 4, may = 5, june = 6)

gsubfn("\\w+", parameters, "label: april, may, june")
```

**2.** or try `fn$` from the same package:

```
with(parameters, fn$identity("$label: $april, $may, $june"))
```

**3.** Here is a short infix function that transforms a format string and a list of parameters to a `sprintf` and then runs it:

```
library(gsubfn)
`%format%` <- function(fmt, list) {
    pat <- "%\\(([^)]*)\\)"
    fmt2 <- gsub(pat, "%", fmt)
    list2 <- list[strapplyc(fmt, pat)[[1]]]
    do.call("sprintf", c(fmt2, list2))
}
```

Use it like this:

```
> '%(label)s: %(april)d %(may)d %(june)d' %format% parameters
[1] "months: 4 5 6"
```

Comment: This is beautiful, thank you. I knew `gsubfn` would be the key to the solution. I've been a fan of your work since the R-help days.

Comment: This is a nice solution!

Answer (score 6):

Although this is not built in to the system `sprintf` functions that R is using (see `man printf` for the system docs), it's easy enough to implement such a feature in R by replacing the named references with their respective positions -

```
sprintf_named <- function(fmt, ...) {
  args <- list(...)
  argn <- names(args)
  if(is.null(argn)) return(sprintf(fmt, ...))

  for(i in seq_along(args)) {
    if(argn[i] == "") next;
    fmt <- gsub(sprintf("%%{%s}", argn[i]), sprintf("%%%d$", i), fmt, fixed = TRUE)
  }

  do.call(sprintf, append(args, fmt, 0))
}
```

Here is an example usage:

```
sprintf_named("%{HIA}s!! %{RYLAH}s", RYLAH="Rock You Like a Hurricane", HIA="Here I Am")
## [1] "Here I Am!! Rock You Like a Hurricane"
```

We could also make it an infix:

```
`%format%` <- function(left, right) do.call(sprintf_named, append(right, left, 0))

"%{b}s %{a}s" %format% list(a='ya', b='boo')
## [1] "boo ya"
```