# Is there a string formatting operator in R similar to Python's %?

Tags: python, r, string, format

I have a url that I need to send a request to using date variables. The https address takes the date variables. I'd like to assign the dates to the address string using something like the formatting operator % in Python. Does R have a similar operator or do I need to rely on paste()?

```
# Example variables
year = "2008"
mnth = "1"
day = "31"
```

This is what I would do in Python 2.7:

```
url = "https:.../KBOS/%s/%s/%s/DailyHistory.html" % (year, mnth, day)
```

Or using .format() in 3.+.

The only I'd know to do in R seems verbose and relies on paste:

```
url_start = "https:.../KBOS/"
url_end = "/DailyHistory.html"
paste(url_start, year, "/", mnth, "/", day, url_end)
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe something like `paste(url_start, paste(year,mnth,day,sep="/"), url_end)`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475803/sprintf-format-strings-reference-by-name/17476306#17476306

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The equivalent in R is `sprintf`:

```
year = "2008"
mnth = "1"
day = "31"
url = sprintf("https:.../KBOS/%s/%s/%s/DailyHistory.html", year, mnth, day)
#[1] "https:.../KBOS/2008/1/31/DailyHistory.html"
```

Also, although I think it is an overkill, you could define an operator yourself too.

```
`%--%` <- function(x, y) {

  do.call(sprintf, c(list(x), y))

}

"https:.../KBOS/%s/%s/%s/DailyHistory.html" %--% c(year, mnth, day)
#[1] "https:.../KBOS/2008/1/31/DailyHistory.html"
```

Comment: Maybe also worth showing an example illustrating vectorization like `"https:.../KBOS/%s/%s/%s/DailyHistory.html" %--% list(1999:2000, mnth, day)` or the sprintf equivalent. (I guess in python they would loop this sort of thing instead.)

Comment: Gets tricky when you've got other percentage characters in your text...for example an SQL query with wildcard operators.

Answer (score 49):

As an alternative to `sprintf`, you might want to check out [`glue`](https://tidyverse.github.io/glue/).

**Update:** In [stringr](http://stringr.tidyverse.org) 1.2.0 they've added a wrapper function of `glue::glue()`, [`str_glue()`](http://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_glue.html)

```r
library(glue)

year = "2008"
mnth = "1"
day = "31"
url = glue("https:.../KBOS/{year}/{mnth}/{day}/DailyHistory.html")

url

#> https:.../KBOS/2008/1/31/DailyHistory.html
```

Answer (score 15):

The `stringr` package has the `str_interp()` function:

```
year = "2008"
mnth = "1"
day = "31"
stringr::str_interp("https:.../KBOS/${year}/${mnth}/${day}/DailyHistory.html")
```

> ```
> [1] "https:.../KBOS/2008/1/31/DailyHistory.html"
> ```

or using a list (note that now numeric values are passed):

```
stringr::str_interp("https:.../KBOS/${year}/${mnth}/${day}/DailyHistory.html", 
                            list(year = 2008, mnth = 1, day = 31))
```

> ```
> [1] "https:.../KBOS/2008/1/31/DailyHistory.html"
> ```

BTW, formatting directives can also be passed, e.g., if the month fields needs to be two characters wide:

```
stringr::str_interp("https:.../KBOS/${year}/$[02i]{mnth}/${day}/DailyHistory.html", 
                    list(year = 2008, mnth = 1, day = 31))
```

> ```
> [1] "https:.../KBOS/2008/01/31/DailyHistory.html"
> ```

Comment: this is the closest to the flexible `format` in python. looks quite nice.